# Support of input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb

Tags: css, input, webkit

Does somebody know which browser versions of chrome, chrome canary and safari support `input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

until safari 5.1, Chrome 21 and earlier. in other words Webkit 5533.22.3